# How to cleanup workspaces in Jenkins controller node?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm looking for a way to cleanup Jenkins workspaces in the controller node specifically.

A lot of similar questions suggest [Workspace Cleanup](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ws-cleanup/) plugin but if I understand correctly it cleans up workspaces only in agents where the pipeline is run.

For now my solution was to have a cronjob that runs a couple of times a day to clean up the older workspaces directories:

```bash
find /var/lib/jenkins/workspace -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +2 -print0 | xargs -0 sudo rm -rf
```

But the problem is that with a lot of pull request when "Scan Multibranch Pipeline" is run all the removed workspaces are pulled again and the Jenkins controller fills up.